# telegram api, can i launch video live streamings?

Tags: telethon, telegram-api, tdlib

I'm so bit confused about Telegram API/TlDB options. In the telegram docs, says that with the telegram-api you can do (programmatically) everything that can do with the app as a user.

I used telethon (python) library to do some tests, but i struggle when i tried to do things like launch or schedule a video stream in a channel (programmatically) and more complex methods.

Is this a possibility? I didn't find the live stream method.

Answer (score 2):

Dude, I understand you. I myself have been looking for a very long time how to implement such a thing. In general, this cannot be done through telethon, but there is another library tgcall that perfectly copes with the stream sound on the air.
But only the sound...
And one cool girl remade this library and now you can stream and videos too)
https://github.com/EverythingSuckz/tgvc-video-tests

Comment: Thanks @Вадим! I will try the solution and if it works i will edit my question :)